# C++ - How do you convert from String to TCHAR*?

Tags: c++

Here's my code:

```
string str = "Hello!";
TCHAR* tch = new TCHAR[str.length() + 1];
mbstowcs_s(NULL, tch, _tcslen(tch), str.c_str(), str.length());
// Use tch for other stuff...
delete [] tch; // Gives debug heap corruption assertion
```

For some reason I'm getting a heap corruption assertion with this code.  I'm racking my brain trying to figure what could be wrong.  I can't find any good documentation for the similarities and differences between strings and tchars which would help me figure this out on my own.

Comment: You can still store `tch` in a `std::basic_string<TCHAR>` in C++11, or `std::vector<TCHAR>` to keep RAII. Both allow you to edit the buffer directly given the C++11 constraint on the string option.

Comment: Since you're using `mbstowcs_s` the destination must be a wide character string. So why bother with `TCHAR`s and `_tcslen`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`_tcslen(tch)` gives the wrong result since `tch` is not initialized at this point. I assume you should pass `str.length() + 1` (the size of the buffer) there.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to use `_tcslen` on tch before you initialize its contents.

From the looks of things you want something closer to:

```
mbstwcs_s(NULL, tch, str.length(), str.c_str(), str.length());
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking about C++ use [ATL string conversion classes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/87zae4a3%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) for that instead of manual memory management and WinApi calls:

```
string str = "Hello!";
CA2T tstr(str.c_str());

SomeFunctionT(tstr);
```

Also you can use those classes inline:

```
string str = "Hello!";

SomeFunctionT(CA2T(str.c_str()));
```

Note: you need to include atlbase.h.